# How to split each value using delimiter in each column for a specific row in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame where there are specific rows that are in error meaning two rows have been combined into one indicated by whitespaces. I have the indices of those rows where the error(s) are and am looking to build a function using the indices to simply create either two new lists that I can then insert into the data frame (as 2 rows) and replace the incorrect row.

I have the following dataframe in R (row 3 is an error):

```
   Location  V1  V2  V3  V4
1       nyc   2  20   9   2
2       bos   4   5   3   8
3 atl m dal 1 4 3 4 1 3 5 2
4       mia   3   1   8   4

structure(list(Location = c("nyc", "bos", "atl m dal", "mia"), 
    V1 = c("2", "4", "1 4", "3"), V2 = c("20", "5", "3 4", "1"
    ), V3 = c("9", "3", "1 3", "8"), V4 = c("2", "8", "5 2", 
    "4")), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Step 1:** The desired output would be two lists/vectors (for each error row) as such:

```
atl m
1
3
1
5

dal 
4
4
3
2
```

**Step 2:** Once I have those lists, I should be able to insert/add them to the existing dataframe  as rows (and delete the error rows) as such:

```
  Location V1 V2 V3 V4
1      nyc  2 20  9  2
2      bos  4  5  3  8
3    atl m  1  3  1  5
4      dal  4  4  3  2
5      mia  3  1  8  4
```

Looking to get help with step 1 mostly. All columns (V1...V4) except the first have exactly one whitespace which can be used as the delimiter to split each value making it easy but the first column *location* isn't as simple. I will need to subset the string manually for that column based on another list I can match it to.

Comment: Can you add your data using `dput(head(df))` ? How do you know that the row with error is `atl m` and `dal` ? How do you know the location is called `dal`, it is not present in the data.

Comment: @RonakShah. Sorry - I fixed the input data to reflect that and added dput() as well. And I know the error is there because there are two numeric values in each of the numeric columns (v1 to v4) separated by a space. Similarly I can also tell because 'atl m' and 'dal' should be individual locations. To give you more context, I used an imaging scraper tool to convert tables from a PDF to a dataframe but the tool wasn't able to convert all rows correctly and hence why I need a workaround to clean up what remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can identify the rows that have error which have whitespace (`\\s`) in them. Create a separate dataframe of such rows. Getting the `location` is not straight-forward since we have lot of whitespace in them. The logic which I have used is the last word goes into the new row while everything before it stays in the same row.

Finally, we combine the two dataframes to get one complete dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)
inds <- grep('\\s', df$V1)

tmp <- df[inds, ]

tmp %>%
  tidyr::separate_rows(everything(), sep = '(\\s)(?!.*\\s)') %>%
  bind_rows(df[-inds, ]) %>%
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE)

#  Location    V1    V2    V3    V4
#  <chr>    <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1 atl m        1     3     1     5
#2 dal          4     4     3     2
#3 nyc          2    20     9     2
#4 bos          4     5     3     8
#5 mia          3     1     8     4
```

Comment: Simple and gets the rows separated!  Is there any way to easily keep the order of the rows with this approach? It will be ordered by the newly created rows first followed by the original rows since a new data frame was created. If I'm able to keep the same row order, I can then easily override the ```Location``` as I have a list of what the values in the right order should be for that column.

Comment: To keep the order you can add a row number column. `df <- df %>% mutate(row = row_number())` and then use the above answer and finally use `arrange(row)` to get data in sorted order and remove the `row` column if not needed.

Comment: Works! You just need to recast ```row``` as numeric as it gets converted to character when you use ```separate_rows```

Comment: Yeah..right. But I think it is better to exclude `row` from `separate_rows` since we don't want to separate `row` column. `tidyr::separate_rows(-row, sep = '(\\s)(?!.*\\s)') %>%` So this will avoid the numeric conversion.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little crude, but you can just copy the problem row, and take the first half of the " " split as the first row ("atl m") and then second half as the "dal" row:

```
tibble(df) %>%
  mutate(across(.fns = ~str_replace(., " \\w+$", ""))) %>%
  add_row(
    df %>% 
      slice(3) %>%
      mutate(across(.fns = ~str_replace(., "^.* (\\w+)$", "\\1")))
  )

# A tibble: 5 x 5
  Location V1    V2    V3    V4   
  <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 nyc      2     20    9     2    
2 bos      4     5     3     8    
3 atl m    1     3     1     5    
4 mia      3     1     8     4    
5 dal      4     4     3     2
```